# Print message after Target Clean (CMake)

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I want to print a message after the target `clean` executed successfully.
I tried like

```
add_custom_command ( TARGET clean POST_BUILD
     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Cleanup done in Project '${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}'"
)
```

but CMake claims that *"No TARGET 'clean' has been created in this directory."*
Of course `clean` is not created in this directory, CMake should generate this target by itself.

Is there any other way to edit `clean` or add instructions?

Comment: Is printing a message after the `clean` target all you really want to do? Why? What is the purpose of the message? what problem is it supposed to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO clean should not be changed or modified, since the user expects a clearly defined behavior.

Do it that way:

```
add_custom_target(CustomClean
    COMMAND ${your_commands}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target clean --config $<CONFIG>
)
```